# working with list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries look bellow

```
raw_list = [
    {"item_name": "orange", "id": 12, "total": 2},
    {"item_name": "apple", "id": 12},
    {"item_name": "apple", "id": 34, "total": 22},
]
```

Expected output should be

```
[
    {"item_name": ["orange", "apple"], "id": 12, "total": 2},
    {"item_name": "apple", "id": 34, "total": 22},
]
```

but how i got

```
[
    {"item_name": "orangeapple", "id": 12, "total": 2},
    {"item_name": "apple", "id": 34, "total": 22},
]
```

Here my code bellow

```
comp_key = "id"
conc_key = "item_name"
res = []
for ele in test_list:
    temp = False
    for ele1 in res:
        if ele1[comp_key] == ele[comp_key]:
            ele1[conc_key] = ele1[conc_key] + ele[conc_key]
            temp = True
            break
    if not temp:
        res.append(ele)
```

how to resolve...?

Comment: You might have a better time grouping your items by `id` first, then working within those groups.

Comment: Fwiw it’s best to have a consistent data format. Make item_name in the output a list always. It will be simpler to create and use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - the special sauce is the `isinstance` stuff to make sure you're making the concatenated value a list instead.

Do note that this assumes the raw list is ordered by the `comp_key` (`id`), and will misbehave if that's not the case.

```
raw_list = [
    {"item_name": "orange", "id": 12, "total": 2},
    {"item_name": "apple", "id": 12},
    {"item_name": "apple", "id": 34, "total": 22},
]

comp_key = "id"
conc_key = "item_name"
grouped_items = []
for item in raw_list:
    last_group = grouped_items[-1] if grouped_items else None
    if not last_group or last_group[comp_key] != item[comp_key]:  # Starting a new group?
        grouped_items.append(item.copy())  # Shallow-copy the item into the result array
    else:
        if not isinstance(last_group[conc_key], list):
            # The concatenation key is not a list yet, make it so
            last_group[conc_key] = [last_group[conc_key]]
        last_group[conc_key].append(item[conc_key])
print(grouped_items)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.@AKX. This answer is more impact. I am getting output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_list)
dd = pd.concat([df.groupby('id')['item_name'].apply(list), df.groupby('id').['total'].apply(sum)], axis=1).reset_index()
dd.to_dict('records')
```

you could use pandas to group by and apply function to two columns then convert to dict

```
[{'id': 12, 'item_name': ['orange', 'apple'], 'total': 2.0},
 {'id': 34, 'item_name': ['apple'], 'total': 22.0}]
```

Comment: Thanks @galaxyan. I am getting invalid syntax while executing above cod, so i am improving above code `import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_list)
dd = pd.concat([df.groupby('id')['item_name'].apply(list), df.groupby('id')['total'].apply(sum)], axis=1).reset_index()
dd.to_dict('records')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.grouper` for grouping by id and `collections.defaultdict` to combine values with same keys into lists.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

id_getter = lambda x: x['id']
gp = groupby(sorted(raw_list, key=id_getter), key=id_getter)

out = []
for _,i in gp:
    subdict = defaultdict(list)
    for j in i:
        for k,v in j.items():
            subdict[k].append(v)
    out.append(dict(subdict))

out
```

Working with complex datatypes such as nested lists and dictionaries, I would advice really utilizing the APIs provided by `collections` and `itertools`.

Comment: But when checked this every thing in list `[{'item_name': ['orange', 'apple'], 'id': [12, 12], 'total': [2]}, {'item_name': ['apple'], 'id': [34], 'total': [22]}]`. But @AKX answer is more impact to me

Comment: please check @paul rooney's comments about a consistent data format. working with a dict with different data formats among values (or keys) is going to overcomplicate what you are trying to achieve. Instead, when you are fetching something from this mapping just take the single value that you need from it at that time. having one value as list and another as string or int is bad practice.

Comment: This is the sole reason why `collections` allows a list type default (or dict type etc) for dict values. Infact having a `defaultdict(list)` allows you to instantly convert it to a dataframe as well if you want to work with pandas later. This is also the reason why @galaxyan has to apply 2 groupby (or more) statements and then concatenating it, instead of just simply grouping once.